# How to exclude folder using sparse checkout

Tags: git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a git repo (call it project A) with a submodule included (project B). Project B is sometimes deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk as a standalone app, and sometimes it is included in Project A as a submodule where it is also deployed to elastic beanstalk. The problem I am having is the .ebextensions folder in project B contains scripts that are being run when project A is deployed. These scripts break the deploy of project A. The current solution is to run `rm` on the .ebextensions folder in project B before running `eb deploy` on project A. How would I create a sparse checkout of project B so that the .ebextensions folder is excluded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going with a docker deploy so that we did not have to configure the repo every time.